# Use Websockets in GWT's DevMode

Tags: gwt, websocket, jetty

has anyone an idea, how to run my app in DevMode with a working WebsocketConnection?
First I thought the missing jetty jars (websocket, continuation, http, io, server and util) were the reason for errors, because when i compiled the app and put it on an external jetty, there was no problem with WebsocketConnection.
So i searched for them and added them to my project. 
But now everytime i start it in DevMode i get an exceptionlike this:

```
[WARN] /testchat/WebSocketChatServlet
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory.upgrade(WebSocketFactory.java:197)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory.acceptWebSocket(WebSocketFactory.java:304)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketServlet.service(WebSocketServlet.java:78)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:513)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

[ERROR] 500 - GET /testchat/WebSocketChatServlet (127.0.0.1) 3129 bytes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DevMode's embedded server is Jetty 6, which doesn't support WebSockets. Google tried to upgrade it to Jetty 7 a couple years ago, but there were issues with classloaders that they couldn't work out.

The only way to use WebSockets is to use an external server (or, if you can solve the classloading issues, write your own [`ServletContainerLauncher`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/ext/ServletContainerLauncher.html)) and run DevMode in `-noserver` mode.
See [Using my own server in development mode instead of GWT's built-in Jetty instance](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s)

Comment: Thomas, are you interested in our helping you with this?  Note the other answer here from Jan.

Comment: Yeah sure! Note that not only GWT needs to be updated, but also the AppEngine SDK. Also, I for one am promoting Maven, with separation of server and client code into distinct modules, which means you don't use DevMode's embedded server, but it's still needed at least for GWT JUnit tests. Don't hesitate to drop a mail on https://groups.google.com/d/forum/google-web-toolkit-contributors and TIA

Answer (score 10):

The Jetty team is only too happy to help Google port GWT to jetty-7. We have actually contacted them several times about it over the space of a couple of years, including sending along code, however we've never had a response from them. So Google, if you're listening, we're here to help :)

Jan

Comment: @Thomas in the other comment is a member of the GWT steering committee, maybe you could ping to him about this.